# XSLT assign field value to variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to xslt and having trouble with what should seemlily be an easy task. I want to take a value of a field from an input xml file, assign it to a variable and the try to output that varible. Seems easy enough but can't seem to get it to work?

XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AUTHENTICATOR>
<LOGINID>johndoe</LOGINID> 
<DATE>06022015</DATE> 
<USERTOKEN> 
    <vLk3pRdlQXX1JcO2s1QzAJfU050>
</USERTOKEN> 
<USERINFO> 
    <field value="John" name="FirstName"/> 
    <field value="Doe" name="LastName"/> 
    <field value="johndoe@hotmail.com" name="Email"/> 
</USERINFO> 
</AUTHENTICATOR>
```

XSLT transform file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF‐8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/AUTHENTICATOR">

<USERINFO>
    <!--Set Variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="UserName" select="field[@name='FirstName']"></xsl:variable>

    <!--Output Variables-->
    <xsl:text>First Name: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$UserName" />     
</USERINFO>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Your XML isn't well-formed... the vLk3pRdlQXX1JcO2s1QzAJfU050 tag isn't closed)

Assuming the XML is well-formed, the following XSLT should work...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/AUTHENTICATOR">
    <USERINFO>
        <!--Set Variables-->
        <xsl:variable name="UserName" select="USERINFO/field[@name='FirstName']/@value"></xsl:variable>
        <!--Output Variables-->
        <xsl:text>First Name: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$UserName" />
    </USERINFO>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mind the context. When you matched the Authenticator node you are in the context of this node. The xpath "field" doesnt lead to any nodes because there arent any in the context auf "Authenticator". Maybe try USERINFO/field instead!

Comment: I tried adding the USERINFO path and it still is not working?

Comment: yeah you now propably have the correct node in your variable, but you write the string-value of this node in your result document. which is an empty string, because your Information is in Attribute-children of your variable. try `<xsl:value-of select="$UserName/@value" />`

Comment: That didn't seem to do it either.